# Unable to restrict admin permission on login to loopback using admin on rest

Tags: loopbackjs, admin-on-rest

I am creating a web application, in which I use **REST** for user interface and for REST API I use using **Loopback**. My user, acl, rollmapping, role table are in mySQL. In my project i am able control access permission when i am trying with loopback UI(after login and setting the access token). But when I am trying with admin on rest UI I am able to login but not able to control the access, in admin on rest I have give all the url and everything in `authClient.jsx`. My `authClient.jsx` file:

```
const request = new Request('http://localhost:3004/api/Users/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
    headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
});
```

Can anybody help me fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use AOR Permissions

https://github.com/marmelab/aor-permissions

This will handle all authentication and role based access.

On the API side you will need to create a custom Login Method that will also return the user role in the request.

something like below

```
    User.customLogin = (credentials, cb) => {
        User.login(credentials, 'User', function(err, token) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err)
                return cb(err)
            }
            app.models.RoleMapping.findOne({where: {principalId: token.userId}, include: {relation: 'role'}}, function(err, rolemap) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err)
                    return cb(err)
                }
                token.role = rolemap.role().name
                return cb(null, token)
            })
        })
    }
```

Save the user role in localStorage on login and then you can use AOR permissions to show role based views to every user.

**EDIT**:
According to AOR star contributor @gildas below. AOR Permissions is going to be deprecated and all features moved to AOR Core. So please check your versions of AOR and decide accordingly.

Comment: aor-permissions is going to be deprecated with the upcoming 1.3.0 version of admin-on-rest. Indeed, it's features have been merged into the core package.

Comment: @kunalpareek can you take a look at this: https://github.com/kimkha/aor-loopback/issues/15

Comment: Have replied there.

Comment: Thought github isnt how AOR would like to handle questions. These kind of questions are best left for StackOverflow